# Preencher valores em um vetor e perguntar posição e os valores

Tags: java, array

```
public class teste4 {
 Scanner op = new Scanner(System.in);
  int[] vetor = new int[10];{
  for (int i = 0; i < vetor.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("Digite o valor da posição " + i);
        vetor[i] = op.nextInt();

    }

  }
```

Como proceder?

Comment: Você poderia esclarecer um pouco o que quis dizer com a sua dúvida? Você já preencheu um vetor de 10 posições com sucesso, o que mais precisa fazer?

Comment: Quero sob que o usuario digite o valor da posição e o valor dela Math

Comment: A diferença então é simplesmente o fato de que o código atual não pergunta a posição, apenas o valor, correto?

Comment: Correto, soh falta isso

Comment: Mais dúvidas me surgiram :) é que eu achei que seu programa ficaria um pouco estranho do jeito que você falou, pois você terá que tratar diversas situações que podem causar uma falha na execução do seu programa, por exemplo: como você pretende tratar os casos que os usuários digitarem um valor fora da faixa de índices que o vetor possui, exemplo: seu vetor vai de 0 a 9, daí o usuário digita 10, ou pior, ele digita `Z`? E se o usuário repetir o valor de um índice que ele já informou? E se ele não quiser preencher os 10, ele pode parar? O que espera que o programa faça nesses casos?

Comment: Oi, Anderson, bem vindo ao [pt.so]. Quando alguém pede esclarecimentos, clique em [edit] e atualize o post com novas informações. Depois é só avisar com @, `@fulano, atualizei a pergunta`. Pelo que vi das suas respostas também, sugiro a leitura dos pequenos guias [answer] e [ask]. Boa sorte!

Answer (score 1):

A solução a seguir utiliza dois tipos de loop:

- o `do...while` para o usuário selecionar a posição do vetor que ele quer preencher e em seguida preenchendo este valor
- o `for` "printa" o vetor populado.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class teste4 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner op = new Scanner(System.in);
    int[] vetor = new int[10];
    int i;

    do {
      int y;

      System.out.println("Digite a posição do vetor de 0 a 9 (-1 para sair):");
      i = op.nextInt();

      if (i != -1) {
        System.out.println("Informe o valor da posição " + i + ":");
        y = op.nextInt();

        vetor[i] = y;
      }
    } while (i > -1);

    for (i = 0; i < vetor.length; i++) {
      System.out.println("Valor da posição: " + i + ": " + vetor[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Bem vindo ao Stackoverflow. Seria interessante explicar os trechos de código da sua solução.

Comment: Obrigado @Renang. A solução acima utiliza 2 tipos de loop: 1ª. o do...while para o usuário selecionar a posição do vetor que ele quer preencher e em seguida preenchendo este valor
2º. o for "printa" o vetor populado.